# Decrypt PBKDF2 with OpenSSL 1.0.1e

Tags: linux, openssl

I need to decrypt a document with openssl:

```
Method : PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256
Salt : saltexample
Passphrase : mypassphrase
```

I tried the command :

```
 openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -md sha256 -pbkdf2 -in file.csv.enc -out file.txt
```

but i get the following error :

```
unknown option '-pbkdf2'
```

Does any one knows the correct command for this version of openssl  : OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb ?2013

Comment: `openssl enc` supports `-pbkdf2` only in release 1.1.1. You must use a newer OpenSSL, possibly on a newer or different system (you didn't say which of the thousands of Linux distros you are using). Also you need to know the number of iterations, and use a salt of exactly 8 bytes, which must be in the file in a specific format (i.e. you may need to add it). Alternatively, you need to write code, which unlike this Q could be ontopic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an old version of OpenSSL which does not include it (well it does support RFC2898, but it is pretty poorly documented and it's not possible to specify on the enc command line)

I don't have that version handy on me (appears RHEL7 has it by default) to man it but if you check the respective online manpages - it shows this bought into 1.1.1:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/enc.html
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html

So it should now be apparent, upgrading OpenSSL is the easiest fix for this.

Download/Wget the appropriate tar from here:
https://www.openssl.org/source/

Then make install:

```
# cd $openssl-version-you-downloaded
# ./config
# make
# make test
# make install
```

Then:

```
# mv /usr/bin/openssl /root/
# ln -s /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
```

Then run your command again.